# how can open a file exemple (pdf file) using a button in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i use a button in kivy on prssed open file (pdf file)
how can open a file exemple (pdf file) in Kivy ?

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Do you want to print what is in the pdf file on the screen?

Comment: i want just open a file pdf when click on button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into the solution by tshirtman for a minimal pdf viewer deployed in kivy:
https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/2552c4bcbc3d9766e80809b494f35a78